# Unable to Type Comma and Period in the Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Currently, I can only type in numbers in the input field, but I would like to type in comma "," and period "." as well so I can type in number with format such as 3,456.78 in the input field. But I'm not sure where I need to fix to allow that to happen. Please help. https://codesandbox.io/s/number-field-currency-ts-kpylkw?file=/src/App.tsx:2069-2153

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export interface NumberFieldInterface {
  convertStringToNumber?: (value: string) => number;
  convertNumberToString?: (value: number) => string;
  onChange?: (value: number) => void;
  value: number;
}

const NumberField = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, NumberFieldInterface>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const {
      value,
      onChange,
      convertStringToNumber,
      convertNumberToString
    } = props;
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    let convertedValue;

    const onValueChange = (value: string) => {
      if (typeof onChange === "function" && convertStringToNumber) {

        convertedValue = convertStringToNumber(value);
  
        const isNumber =
          typeof convertedValue === "number" && isFinite(convertedValue);

        if (isNumber) {
          onChange(convertedValue);
        }
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={ref}
          value={convertNumberToString?.(value)}
          onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
      
            onValueChange(e.currentTarget.value)
          }
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<number>(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleChange = (val: number) => {
    setInputValue(val);
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NumberField
        ref={ref}
        convertStringToNumber={(val) => {

          return Number(val);
        }}
        convertNumberToString={(val) => {

          return val.toString();
        }}
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are converting the string to a number (`Number(val)`) all extra formatting will be lost. If you want to maintain it, why not just keep the value as a string and turn it into a number when it's used? (Or maintain two states, a `displayValue` and `numberValue`)

Comment: The other way can be to put validation on onBlur method instead of onChange.

Comment: So when a user type in 3,444.56, behind the scene it will converted to 3444.56 number type as a user type in. So onBlur method won't work. So maybe regex needs to be applied in `convertStringToNumber` ?

Comment: If, when a user tries to type "3." it's always corrected to "3", that would mean the user cannot input "3.4". I guess "3." should only be changed to "3" on blur.

Comment: Would you know a way to solve this issue using two states like DBS above mentioned? Prefer solving it without using onBlur if possible.